# Oracle - Ayuda con consulta con un campo fecha y dos tipos de eventos diferentes para mostrar una sola fila

Tags: oracle

tengo una tabla que registra unos eventos de entrada y salida, en ella se guarda la fecha con hora, el id del usuario y el tipo de evento.

TABLA:

```
  TABLA_ID | USUARIO_ID | FECHA_HORA          | TIPO_EVENTO
  1        | 1          | 2018-08-01 18:14:22 | ENTRADA
  2        | 1          | 2018-08-01 18:20:02 | SALIDA
  3        | 1          | 2018-08-01 18:25:22 | ENTRADA
  4        | 1          | 2018-08-01 18:30:22 | SALIDA
```

la cuestión es que debo armar una consulta SQL que me permita mostrar los eventos de la siguiente manera:

```
USUARIO_ID | FECHA      | HORA ENTRADA | HORA SALIDA
1          | 2018-08-01 | 18:14:22     | 18:20:02
1          | 2018-08-01 | 18:25:22     | 18:30:02
```

Agradecería mucho si me pueden brindar alguna idea de una consulta, ya que hasta ahora no he podido y no se me ocurre una solución :(

La base de datos es Oracle en su versión 12C.

Comment: me imagino que la tabla seguira aumentando infinitamente verdad?

Comment: Si, la tabla constantemente recibe datos.

Comment: ¿La información de la tabla es consistente? es decir, ¿cronológicamente ordenada la tabla, voy a tener una entrada y luego una salida? ¿Puede haber dos entradas antes de una salida o viceversa?

Comment: Aunque no es lo que se espera, si hay ocasiones en las que se registra entrada y no se registra salida, o en las que en un mismo día hay dos entradas y una sola salida.

Comment: Al no encontrar una solución mediante SQL se decidió crear un procedimiento PL/SQL que armara en una tabla temporal los datos tal y como se requieren y luego consultar esa tabla temporal para poder generar el reporte. Muchas gracias a todos.